# How to know if the float value is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: java, floating-point, integer, compare

```
// The given input
String input = "99999999.99";

// We need only 2 decimals (in case of more than 2 decimals is in input)
Float value = Float.valueOf(input);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
input = df.format(value);
value = new Float(input);

// Now we have a clear 2 decimal float value
// Check for overflow
value *= 100; // Multiply by 100, because we're working with cents

if (value >= Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
   System.out.println("Invalid value");
}
else {
///
}
```

The statement doesn't work, the condition fails.

Which is the correct way to compare a float with an integer value?

Comment: Note that the precision of `Float` is not good enough to handle the full range of an `Integer`. If you are handling money you should avoid using floating point numbers when possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. 99999999.99 times 100 equals to 9999999999 .
That's larger that `max int == 2147483647` (it's 2^31 -1). If you want to be able to store bigger integer numbers use `long`.

Elaborate further if it's not your problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    // The given input
    String input = "99999999.99";

    // We need only 2 decimals (in case of more than 2 decimals is in input)
    Float value = Float.parseFloat(input);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
    DecimalFormatSymbols custom = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    custom.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(custom);
    input = df.format(value);
    value = new Float(input);

    // Now we have a clear 2 decimal float value
    // Check for overflow
    value *= 100; // Multiply by 100, because we're working with cents

    if (value >= Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        System.out.println("Invalid value");
    } else {
        ///
    }
}
```

Have a nice day

Comment: Your code produce an exception because the decimal separator used was ','